# How to decrease header files in visual assist

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-assist

I installed Visual Assist X. It is useful. But there is a problem. When I enter sentence

> #include " "

. And it shows auto-completion. There too many header files coming to my eyes. And many of them are not in my project !!!
Does someone know how to deal with?

Like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbeXS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can configure in regards to the contents of #include completion lists.  VA reads the include paths defined in the projects of your solution.

If you have stray include directories listed in your project, you could remove them.  Check the following for each combination of project and project configuration:

- Project Properties | Configuration Properties | VC++ Directories
- Project Properties | Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Additional Include Directories